# Database to store arrays of integers and bitset in

Tags: python, database, arrays

I am building a small image search engine that uses image descriptors that are both binary numbers and integer valued (numpy) arrays which are both the 'keys' which should both form the basis for an inverted file like approach. The value is simply the image name/identifier they originated from.

I am looking for a database / caching solution with a python interface that will allow me to quickly search for these keys and not have me worry about memory and disc management.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in Python are instances of the [class array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array)
If you mean "list", use preferably the term 'list'

If I understand correctly, you use a data structure having integers as keys, and binary numbers as values: in Python it's a dictionary

If you want to record this data structure in a file, use the module [cPickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle)

.

#### update

there was a 'hello, welcome' at the beginning of my post... I rewrite it here

Comment: I edited a bit for clarity. I specifically do not want to use my own file for storage.